# Strange JavaScript Number behavior

Tags: javascript, numbers

I found the following weird behavior while working on JavaScript numbers.

```
var baseNum = Math.pow(2, 53);
console.log(baseNum); //prints 9007199254740992

console.log(baseNum + 1); //prints 9007199254740992 again!

console.log(baseNum + 2); //prints 9007199254740994, 2 more than +1

console.log(baseNum + 3) // prints 9007199254740996, 2 more than +2
console.log(baseNum + 4) // prints 9007199254740996, same as +3
```

What is happening here? I understand that JavaScript can only represent numbers upto `2^53` (they are internally 'double'?), but why this behavior?

If `2^53` is the practical max, then why do we have `Number.MAX_VALUE` (`1.7976931348623157e+308`)?.

Comment: `var base`, then `baseNum` everywhere else?

Comment: @MarcB Copy paste demon strikes again! Corrected the error

Comment: Article that goes into more detail at http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html.

Comment: @Bill Thanks, that explains it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number is really a double. The mantissa has 52-bits ([source and extra information on doubles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation)). Therefore, storing 2^53 chops off the one bit.

The number is stored using 3 pieces a sign bit (fairly straight forward) and two other pieces, the mantissa M and the exponent E. The number is calculated as:

(1 + M/2^53) * 2^(E-1023)

I might have some of the specifics there a little off, but the basic idea is there. So when the number is 2^53, 2^(E-1023) = 2^53 and since there are only 52 bits in M, you can no longer represent the lowest bit.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But my gripe is over the behavior on adding 1/2/3... Can you explain that?

Comment: @AshwinPrabhu It *does* explain that, doesn't it?  Because above 2^53 it can't increase in 1s anymore -- it counts in 2s... until it becomes larger and more inaccurate and counts in 4s, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The answer that [@CrazyCasta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12595244/143295) gave is good.

The only thing to add is to your second question:

> If `2^53` is the practical max, then why do we have `Number.MAX_VALUE` (`1.7976931348623157e+308`)?

As you've demonstrated, it **can** store numbers larger than `2^53`, but with precision worse than `2^0`.  As the numbers grow ever larger, they lose more and more precision.

So max value in `Number.MAX_VALUE` means the "largest" value it can represent; but it doesn't mean that accuracy is the same as a value near `2^1` or `2^53`.

A corollary to this is that `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the *smallest* value that Number can contain; not the *most negative*.  That is, it is the closest non-zero number to zero: `5.00E-324` (notice that's a positive number!).

Comment: Here's an analogy: You're in the center of New York City, and you're told that the distance to the center of London is 3465 miles. Now you take a step to the West. It's still 3465 miles to London. The precision of that measurement is in miles, so adding a few inches or feet doesn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value storable in a long is much larger than the maximum value storable **with exact precision** in a long. Floating-point numbers have a fixed maximum number of significant digits, but the magnitude of the number can get much larger.

There are a certain number of bits allocated for an exponent (power of two), and that's implicitly multiplied by the mantissa stored in the rest of the bits. Beyond a certain point, you lose precision, but you can keep incrementing the exponent to represent larger and larger magnitudes.